# Maximum cut vertices of an Eulerian graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees

How can I find maximum number of cut vertices of a Eulerian graph with $n$ vertices?

Comment: Does the graph have to be simple?

Comment: Not necessarily

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I have no idea how to approach the problem although I tried induction on the number of vertices but it was a dead end for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the formula for maximum possible number of vertices in an eulerian graph is $\lfloor\frac{n-3}{2}\rfloor$.

In order to prove it you should us strong induction to prove that the maximum is $\lfloor\frac{n-3k}{2}\rfloor$ which can be done by choosing one of the cut vertices *(v)* and replacing it with *s + 1* other vertices which are the number of subgraphs formed by removing *v* and replacing each edge of *v* with one of the new vertices and the corresponding vertex.
Finally we would have *n + s* vertices and *k + s* sub graphs.
Based on inductions assumption the maximum number of vertices is $\lfloor\frac{n+s-3k-3s}{2}\rfloor + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

First observe that every connected graph contains at least two vertices that are not cut vertices (consider a maximal path, its end-vertices cannot be cut vertices).

So if an Eulerian graph has $n$ vertices, it certainly cannot contain more than $n-2$ cut vertices.

If your Eulerian graph is **not** simple, then there is a nice construction that shows this number $n-2$ is attainable. Hint: it looks a bit like a path.

Comment: Thanks but what if it's simple?

Comment: I don't know. Seems a lot harder.